# How to reset progress bar to zero after 'n' number of iterations? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, loops

I added a progress bar to a WPF application that counts how many times a gesture is performed. But I want the progress bar to reset to zero after 20 iterations.

I tried to achieve this in the below code but when the bar gets to 20 it keeps counting and progress shows full. My question is how do I fix my loop to allow for this?

```
void matcher_GestureMatch(Gesture gesture)
{
    scoreProgBar.Maximum = 20;
    lblGestureMatch.Content = gesture.Name;
    if(scoreCntr == 20)
    {
        scoreCntr.Equals(0);
    }
    scoreCntr++;
    scoreProgBar.Value = scoreCntr;

    lblScoreCntr.Content = scoreCntr;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
scoreCntr.Equals(0);
```

Doesn't do what you probably think it does. It will compare the current object instance (scoreCntr) to the other object passed as the parameter (0).

You probably want something like this:

```
if(scoreCntr == 20)
{
    scoreCntr = 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah it compares if the two `objects` are equal not assigning a value. Should have caught that one.

Comment: We've all been there before ;) If this answers your question, please accept it as the answer so that it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
scoreCntr = 0;
```

not

```
scoreCntr.Equals(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this,

```
void matcher_GestureMatch(Gesture gesture)
{
    scoreProgBar.Maximum = 20;
    lblGestureMatch.Content = gesture.Name;
    if(scoreCntr == 20)
    {
        scoreCntr = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        scoreCntr++;
    }

    scoreProgBar.Value = scoreCntr;
    lblScoreCntr.Content = scoreCntr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**U can try this :

```
        }**` if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }**`
```